# Referencing with Enumerate and Cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, labels, cleveref

I'm struggling to set up correct references using the `cleveref` package. I'm able to get references for the second sub-hierarchy, however, I don't get the reference correctly setup for the first level.

As it can be seen in the screen shot, how can I print "Research Question 1" instead just the simple "1" as it is now?
Any ideas?
[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}

\begin{document}

Specifically, this research aims to address the following questions:

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\itshape Research Question \arabic*},ref=\arabic*, 
leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt, itemsep=0.5em]

\item \label{rq1} First Question
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\itshape RQ \theenumii}, leftmargin=1.25em, labelindent=0pt, itemsep=0.5em]
\item \label{rq1.1} First First Subquestion
\item \label{rq1.2} First Second Subquestion
\end{enumerate}
\item \label{rq2} Second Question
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\itshape RQ \theenumii}, leftmargin=1.25em, labelindent=0pt, itemsep=0.5em]
\item \label{rq2.1} Second First Subquestion
\item \label{rq2.2} Second Second Subquestion
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

% Reference example
Now you can reference sub-questions using cref or aliases:

This text refers to \cref{rq1}

This text refers to \cref{rq1.1} 

This text refers to \cref{rq1.2}



This text refers to \cref{rq2}

This text refers to \cref{rq2.1}

This text refers to \cref{rq2.2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: the image could not be displayed, because the three tick marks at the end of the code block were on the last line of the code block, instead of after the last line of the code block.

Comment: You wrote, " I'm able to get references for the second sub-hierarchy". Are you sure you want both "item" and "RQ" in the prefix label? Wouldn't it make the cross-reference more readable if it said just "RQ"? If you agree, please see the answer I provided.

Comment: @thymaro Thanks for the hint, I edited my post.

Comment: @Mico You're right, that would then be next challenge I need to tackle - of course, I want to have the "item" befor RQ removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you (a) use the `\newlist` and `\setlist` macros of the `enumitem` package to create a bespoke two-level enumerate-like environment -- called `rqenumerate` in the example shown below; (b) keep the `ref` options of the `\setlist` instructions deliberately simple; and (c) use `\crefname` (and, if desired, `\Crefname`) directives to shape how cref-based cross-references to both levels of the `rqenumerate` environments should look like. The advantage of this approach is that it enables you to use multiple arguments when using `\cref` and `\Cref`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref} % note the 'nameinlink' option

% Set up a bespoke enumerate-like enviroment
\newlist{rqenumerate}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[rqenumerate,1]{%
    label=\bfseries\itshape Research Question \arabic*.,
    ref=\arabic*,
    leftmargin=*, labelindent=0pt, itemsep=0.5em}
\setlist[rqenumerate,2]{%
    label=\bfseries\itshape RQ \arabic{rqenumeratei}.\arabic*.,
    ref=\arabic{rqenumeratei}.\arabic*,
    leftmargin=1.25em, labelindent=0pt, itemsep=0.25em}

% define the prefix label strings
\crefname{rqenumeratei}{research question}{research questions}
\crefname{rqenumerateii}{RQ}{RQs}
\Crefname{rqenumerateii}{Research question}{Research questions}


\begin{document}
\noindent
Specifically, this research aims to address the following questions:

\begin{rqenumerate}
\item \label{rq1} First Question
  \begin{rqenumerate}
    \item \label{rq1.1} First First Subquestion
    \item \label{rq1.2} First Second Subquestion
  \end{rqenumerate}
\item \label{rq2} Second Question
  \begin{rqenumerate}
    \item \label{rq2.1} Second First Subquestion
    \item \label{rq2.2} Second Second Subquestion
  \end{rqenumerate}
\end{rqenumerate}

% Reference example
\noindent
Now we can cross-reference questions and sub-questions using \verb+\cref+:

\obeylines % just for this example
This text refers to \cref{rq1}.
This text refers to \cref{rq2}.
\Cref{rq1,rq2} examine \dots
This text refers to \cref{rq1.2}.
\Cref{rq1.1,rq1.2,rq2.1,rq2.2} discuss \dots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow - thank you very @Mico!

Comment: Indeed, that was also my first solution to come up with a customized enumerate environment, however, that didn't work so I tried to locally customize the enumerate environment.
Anyways, thank you for your help!